# Python Virtualenv : ImportError: No Module named Zroya

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was trying to work with python virtualenv on the [Zroya python wrapper around win32 API](https://github.com/malja/zroya). Although I did installed the modules using pip, and although they are shown in cli using the command

```
    pip freeze
```

,when trying to execute the .py file that uses the modules it shows the following error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "TesT.PY", line 2, in <module>
       from zroya import NotificationCenter
    ImportError: No module named 'zroya'
```

What is the reason for this cause ? I'm using python 3.4. When checked on

```
   >>>help("modules")
```

on python cli, the modules that were installed using pip aren't listed.

Comment: so you have `pypiwin32` and did `pip install zroya`

Comment: yes but both aren't shown in the python installed modules and cant be directly used/imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtualEnv is separate from OS Python environment.
Check whether you installed 'zroya' module in OS Python env or virtualEnv.

Run `bin/activate` in your virtual env, and check if 'zroya' module exists

`>>>help("modules")`

If no module named Zroya, **run install command `pip install xxx` after activating virtual env.**

Comment: 'zroya' module is not showing up in the python modules. Even after that when I executed `pip install zroya` it shows that `Requirement already satisfied: zroya in e:\python\zroya - windows notification\python-workspace\lib\site-packages`

Comment: try add `site-packages` dir into `PYTHONPATH` environment viriable

Answer (score 0):

Installing `zroya` should solve your problem.

Installation instructions: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zroya

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with the pip install. Copying the zroya directory from github repository over to PYTHONPATH resolved the conflict.